# ERRNO 111 Connection refused when starting server over SSH

Tags: python, ssh, rpyc

I would like to start a rpyc server on a machine I'm connected with over ssh. The general SSH connection is working but when starting the server I receive ERRNO 111 Connection refused. When starting the server manually, by logging in via SSH on the machine and starting the py file, I can connect. I tried:

`ssh.exec_command("python3 /tmp/recalibration/rpc_service_pictures.py")`
`ssh.exec_command("python3 /tmp/recalibration/rpc_service_pictures.py &")`
`ssh.exec_command("nohup python3 /tmp/recalibration/rpc_service_pictures.py &")`
`ssh.exec_command("nohup python3 /tmp/recalibration/rpc_service_pictures.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &")`

but nothing is changing the Connection Problem, any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you cant be connected via SSH at the same time.
I had an open SSH session at the same time to debug, and because of that I couldnt connect. Seems obvious when you know it, but if you dont you are completely lost :D